# ng-click fails when buttons are removed from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some logic in a directive that is making making a popup. I have buttons that trigger it inside of the directive that I want to use to trigger the modal, but I don't want them to live in the directive. The controller contains an object of different alert types and associated data: `alertBoxMessages`, and the directive looks like this.

```
//controller is up here
})
.directive('ghopAlertBox', [function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                alertBoxMessages: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'myAlert.html',
            link: function(scope){
                scope.alertShown = false;
                scope.showAlert = function (alertObj) {
                    scope.currentAlertBoxMessage = scope.alertBoxMessages[alertObj];
                    scope.alertShown = true;

                };
               scope.closeAlert = function (closeMessage) {
                   closeMessage = closeMessage || false;
                   scope.alertShown = false;
                   document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = closeMessage;

                };
            }
        };
    }]);
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myAlert" ng-controller="alertBox">

<button id="successBtn" ng-click="showAlert('saveSuccess')" alert-box-messages="alertBoxMessages">Success Alert</button>
<button id="warnBtn" ng-click="showAlert('confirmWarning')">Warning Alert</button>
<button id="errorBtn" ng-click="showAlert('fofError')">Error Alert</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<alert-box alert-box-messages="alertBoxMessages"></alert-box>

</body>
```

It works when the buttons are inside the HTML partial `<alert-box>`, but when I take them out, nothing happens on the click. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your HTML into myAlert.html file?

Comment: @Shota I'm not sure I understand the question, sorry.

Comment: You should have "myAlert.html" file in your working directory, and move your buttons there.

Comment: @Shota no that's the problem. I can't have the buttons there.

Comment: Your directive uses a different scope to its parent. If you want to arrange your html + directive like this, you'll have to figure out how to do it with `scope: false`